Correct Tool to Remove and Install a Shimano Octalink Bottom Bracket
My bike is a KTM Ultra Flite with 26 inches wheels from 2010. I have recently replaced chain, cassette and chainrings as explained in this post. Since I have now learned to replace these parts, I would like to be able to also remove the bottom bracket so that I can clean it from time to time and also to have the possibility to replace it when it will be needed as the bike is getting quite old. I believe that the bottom bracket is a Shimano Octalink, but I am not 100% sure. I enclose a photo that shows the bottom bracket, hopefully it is helpful. If not, how can I clearly determine which BB my bike has? My main question is what is the right tool to remove/install it? Is the Park Tool BBT-22 the correct tool?
In addition, do you have any suggestion for a torque wrench (to be used with the BBT-22 or alternative) similar to the Park tool TW-6.2 but that has better bang for the buck value?
Thank you in advance for any comment.

UPDATE:
I add a photo to show how the BBT-22 fits in my BB. Hopefully it can help other readers to judge whether it's the right tool or not.


Nice update pic.  Just a suggestion: if you are able to clean the bike before working on it, it makes maintenance more pleasant.  I realize this is a commuter and as such they do get dirty with use, but a pre-clean prior to major maintenance is worth it IMO.

Thanks Ted, you are right it needs to be better cleaned. The problem is that the place where I live is very rainy during this period and the bike gets full of mud almost every day :)
From the photo you can see the BT-22 inserted in the BB. It doesn't fully insert the BB, but it enters something like half way. Do you think it is expected? Do I need a special tool to hold it in place while rotating it?

I realize you got to do what you can when you can regarding cleaning the bike. Sometimes, a clean bike is a luxury you cannot reach due to conditions.  As long as the tool engages the splines of the BB enough it should be good.  Make sure that there is no dried mud or other debris in the BB splines preventing it from being fully inserted (back to that clean-bike thing ;).  Similar to if a hex bolt had dirt in it preventing the hex key from being fully inserted, you would clean out the dirt before loosening or tightening the hex bolt. Other than that, if it fully engages, you are good.

Also, be aware that the drive side of your BB is a left-handed thread.  The non-drive side (the left side) is "normal."  But the right side (drive train side) is opposite that. It is that way so it does not unscrew/loosen during use (same reason pedals are threaded opposite each other).  It is worth looking at pictures of how to loosen/tighten a BB online.  Here is a local link to get you oriented as well: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/81908/drive-side-part-of-bottom-bracket-is-impossible-to-remove-and-has-destroyed-tool

Thanks a lot and great point about the correct direction for unscrewing the BB. I haven´t tried yet but I didn´t know before you mentioned, thus I could have ended up over tightening and maybe damaging the threads. I have now watched a video about the BBT-22 and it seems the depth it enters my BB is correct.

To check, count the outer ring of splines on the BB. If yours has 20 splines the BBT-22 is the one for you. That looks like an Octalink 2 bottom bracket with 9mm splines so you should be good.
You’ll be wanting a big crescent wrench or a 3/8 socket/breaker bar to remove or install the BB. An expensive high value torque wrench will be overkill if you don’t already own one. Your wrist-o-meter and common sense will be enough for this component on this bike.
That isn’t general advice. Using correctly torqued bolts is advisable in most lower (4-14 Nm) torque specs. For cassette lock rings and bottom brackets where a wide range of high torque is specified you can be satisfied with “quite a lot but not a stupid amount” to avoid buying a $100+ tool you might use once every 1-2 years.
In general, regular grade cartridge bottom brackets are sealed consumable units so you install and use them until they get play or start grinding. There is never any need to clean or lube them.

Thanks @Warren for the help. I have checked and my BB has 20 splines. I have now got the BBT-22 and it seems to fit. It doesn't fully insert the BB, but it enters something like half way. If allowed I can add a photo to the post to show what I mean. Do you think it is expected?

In regards to the torque spec for the bottom bracket, it is 50-70 N-m (37-51 lbf-ft).   It can be found on page 17 of the Shimano Dealers Manual.
Your bottom bracket "may" be the BB-ES300 or a variant of it.
As for a recommendation for a torque wrench, you are getting into the opinion area which is discouraged for this site. However, a good torque wrench is a valuable tool that is usable for more than bicycle repair and maintenance. Because they are precision instruments, it warrants discerning your purchase. Personally, I recently purchased several (1/2, 3/8, and 1/4-inch drive, with varying ranges of torque settings for each) that were a reputable name brand and have a calibration sheet included. I verified the calibration with another tool used for calibration as well. That may be a bit more than necessary, but I have a very high confidence that they are good for what I need them for. You will just need to do research on this yourself, as I can only offer general advice/answer to that question.
Here is page 17 of the Dealers Manual for Cranksets and Bottom Brackets, which also includes the torque spec for the crankarms as well:


Old-style "beam deflection" torque wrenches are dirt cheap and sufficiently accurate for this work. A 3/8" drive model should cover the desired torque; if not then a 1/2" drive model.


One plus for a beam-type torque wrench is they stay in calibration  if they are treated well (and assuming they are correct to start with). Their calibration won’t drift with use like a click-type torque wrench can. However, a click torque wrench is nice that it tells you when the correct torque is reached without looking. Either will do the job it is tasked to do.
